# IE7 on XP, how to enable script debugging

Tags: windows-xp, javascript, debug, internet-explorer-7

I have Windows XP SP3 and IE 7.0.5730.13
I need to be able to debug javascript viewing my Website in IE7
I've gone into Internet Options > Advanced and unchecked 'Disable Script Debugging' boxes.
I've installed MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.
After installing MSVWD I get the IE View-menu option 'Script Debugger'
But when I select Script Debugger > Open, nothing happens.
It fails silently to do anything.
When I go to a page that I know has JS errors, I get no notification.

Can someone please let me know what to try next, to get Script Errors to appear?

Comment: Just want to make sure -- you have to restart IE when changing this setting.

Comment: yes, in fact have restarted the PC several times